# ListView based on own class

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

im new in android developing, so i have a problem with Dynamic list.

i have a Habit class  and HabitMemoryDao class and i want to make a ListView in main class
with Habits.
Can somebody wrote the main class where Listview will show all habits.
Thanks

```
public class Habit {

    private String name;
    private Date startDate;
    private int duration;
    private int frequencyInWeek; // from 1 to 7
    private String awardText;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public int getFrequencyInWeek() {
        return frequencyInWeek;
    }

    public void setFrequencyInWeek(int frequency) {
        this.frequencyInWeek = frequency;
    }

    public String getAward() {
        return awardText;
    }

    public void setAward(String award) {
        this.awardText = award;
    }
}

public class HabitMemoryDao {

    private List<Habit> habitList = new LinkedList<Habit>();

    public HabitMemoryDao() {
        Habit habit1 = new Habit();
        habit1.setName("Running");
        habit1.setDuration(30);
        habit1.setFrequencyInWeek(2);
        habit1.setStartDate(new Date());
        habitList.add(habit1);

        Habit habit2 = new Habit();
        habit2.setName("Swimming");
        habit2.setDuration(15);
        habit2.setFrequencyInWeek(7);
        habit2.setStartDate(new Date());
        habitList.add(habit2);
    }


    public List<Habit> getHabitList() {
        return habitList;
    }
```

Comment: your Habit class needs a toString function which would be used to display object content, then you add the habit objects to a list view model iteratively....

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to understand how ListView and Adapters work with each other:

So there are two ways to start: You can use ArrayAdapter, that uses the toString() method of your Habit class to show a list of habits in a ListView or you use the more powerful class BaseAdapter. I would suggest you to learn how BaseAdapter works, since Array adapter is a subclass of BaseAdapter. [Simple tutorial for BaseAdapters](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/)

Btw: It's not a good idea to ask for people who writes you some concrete code. You are welcome to ask questions about concrete problems and people will answer you (most of the times with code snippets).

Answer (score 0):

First add a `toString()` method in your `Habit` class

```
    public class Habit{
    ...

    public String toString()
    {
      return getName()+" "+getStartDate()+" "+getDuration()+" "+getFrequencyInWeek()+" "+getAward();
    }
    ...
}
```

then in your `MainActivity` take a look at this basic `ListView` tutorial and you are going to figure it out.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create own ArrayAdapter. Example implementation:

```
public class HabitAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Habit> {

private ArrayList<Habit> items;
Activity activity;

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView nameTv;
    public TextView startDateTv;
    public TextView awardTextTv;

}

public HabitAdapter(Activity activity, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Habit> items) {
    super(activity, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.items = items;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_for_one_habit, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.nameTv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
        viewHolder.startDateTv = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.startDateTv);
        viewHolder.awardTextTv = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.awardTextTv);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    Habit habit = items.get(position);

    holder.nameTv.setText(habit.getName());
    holder.startDateTv.setText(habit.getStartDate());
    holder.awardTextTv.setText(habit.getAwardText());

    return rowView;
}
```

}

You need to create layout for one row of ListView. Basing on my implementation, you should have there 3 TextViews (nameTv, startDateTv, awardTextTv).

Then in your activity:

```
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
HabitAdapter ha = new HabitAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout_for_one_habit, HabitMemoryDao.getHabitList());
myList.setAdapter(ha);
```